# file system api read/write confusion

Tags: c, filesystems

I tried to read 7 bytes from the file self_tutor.txt into the buff. But somehow the read was not successful. I have checked the syntax for read and the corresponding parameters to be used, but I am not sure where the error comes from. Also what would be the proper way of outputting value from buff if buff was successfully write with the 7 bytes of values from self_tutor.txt?

will a while loop work?

```
// will this work if the total number of bytes is less than I request? like there
// is only 5 bytes in the self_tutor.txt file but I request to read 7? (i.e. short-read)

while(buff!= EOF) {  // will EOF work if I have short-read
   printf("value of character inside the buff:%c\n ", *buff);
   buff++;
}

or should it be:
while(buff!= "\n") {  // so "\n" will be able to handle short-read, is it correct?
   printf("value of character inside the buff:%c\n ", *buff);
   buff++;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    int f1 = open("self_tutor.txt", O_RDONLY);
    char *buff;
    int f2 = read(f1, buff, 7);
      printf("value of f2 :%d\n ", f2); // f2 = -1, so read was not successful
      
     // how to print all the bytes in buff from beginning of buff to end of buff
    printf("value of buff:%c\n ", *buff);
   
    return 0;
}
```

this is the contents of my self_tutor.txt file:

```
In our Y86-64 simulator. This course is pretty interesting but hard.
```

A related question is:
A short read may indicate end of file but does not necessarily do so.

what does it mean, does it mean if I have a short-read the following
read(f1, buff, 7);

will not necessarily produce the value 0?
i.e. read(f1, buff, 7) might equal a non-zero value?

thanks

Comment: It should be *neither* of those options. And your code already runs off the rails because of *undefined behavior* regardless. You're `read`-ing into an address from a pointer with indeterminate value. It points to lord-knows-what-if-anything. Pointers, arrays, system calls, etc., should all be covered in a beginners guide to C. The mistakes you're making have less to do with filesystems, and more to do with a lack of basic understanding of the language and libraries.

Comment: A few things... check `errno` (or `perror`), and you will get more interesting information than "-1".  Also, you might want to check if `open` actually worked as well.  The real error is that you need to declare `buff` with some storage, like `char buff[8];`, as other have mentioned.  Without the other suggestions, though, you might still not work because (e.g.) you have no read permissions on the file or something.  Be sure to check all errors and log anything abnormal.

Answer (score 0):

You code never assigns any value to `buff`. So you are passing garbage to `read`. You need to make `buff` point to the place you want the character you read to be stored before you pass its value to `read`.